# Maintain Session State in my iPhone Application

Tags: objective-c, background, nsuserdefaults

I want to maintain the session in my iphone application. If the application Enters in to Background state or goes inactive So I have to keep same screen which I closed last. How to do this one?

For Instance, In  my app, User have to register only once.. If user successfully registered then user will be moved to next screen so when the user opens the app next time the same screen would be shown. I know that It can be done through NSUserDefaults but how to do in my case ?

Comment: theres nothing unique in your case, store a boolean and if the user has passed registration, don't load the first screen, load the second. Whats the issue?

Comment: Hey Simon thanks for help.. but I don't know how to do it because I'm beginner in iOS and these thing I'm going to do first time.

Comment: `I know that It can be done through NSUserDefaults but how to do in my case` ... if you are a beginner and don't know how to do any of it, this is very misleading. You are saying that you understand it but there is something specific to your case thats different. Nobody here is going to write this for you, you will have to research it, read tutorials and make some effort. Being a beginner is not an excuse for not using google or reading a book, we all had to do it ourselves. If you have a specific issue like "I'm running this code and its throwing error X", come back and ask again

Comment: otherwise nobody will do this, unless you try www.freelancer.com

Comment: Hello Simon..I got the solution but where I have to apply that code that help i need help.  set your boolean by using [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"logged_in"];
read it by using this code
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"logged_in"]) {
    [self displayLogin];
} else {
    [self displayMainScreen];
}

Comment: how / where are you displaying the first screen now?

Comment: I opened the first screen from Appdelegate.m as a rootviewcontroller

Comment: why can't you run this check there?

Comment: I tried as you said but app crashes.. Can I write code in AppDelegate.m ?

Comment: ... never never never come to stackoverflow and say "the app crashes" how is anyone suppose to fix that. What is the error? Do NOT put the error in a comment. Edit your question and place it in a code tag so it will be formatted. Yes you can write code in the appDelegate. If you are asking such a question the only help I can give you is this: http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Objective-C-Edition-Developers-Library/dp/0321967607

Comment: in 4 year i am in competition with you, you are not help me when i am beginner but i am not like you and try to understand the user who is beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**set the value For which page you want to set the session**

**For example I want to save the session for register.m page**

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
defaults setObject:@"1" forKey:@"Register"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

**in my app i have used main.m as firstpage so in viewDidLoad of same page to get value**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
   [super viewDidLoad];
   NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   NSString* strValue =   [defaults objectForKey:@"Register"];

    NSLog(@"NSUserDefaults.....>%@",strValue);

    if ([strValue isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        VerificationViewController *rf = [[VerificationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VerificationViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:rf animated:YES];
    }
}
```

**navigate the page in if condition on which you want to navigate the control when next time the application open by the user**